# Can I use QImage in my code while I'm compiling my project as static lib (undefined reference)?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qmake, qimage

I'm developing project in Qt Creator and I need to draw image in class-member function that is compiled as static lib with no error, but when I try to use this function I get following error:

> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::QImage(int, int, QImage::Format)'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::isNull() const'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::fill(unsigned int)'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::setPixel(int, int, unsigned int)'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::save(QString const&, char const*, int)
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::~QImage()'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'QImage::~QImage()'

So the question is can I use `QImage` with static build lib?

In .pro file I have:

> TEMPLATE = lib
>
> CONFIG += staticlib
>
> QT       += gui

**Edited:** I'm using GCC 4.9 compiler for Android, if compile using MSVC2015 for Windows errors looks like:

> -1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QImage::QImage(int,int,enum QImage::Format)" (__imp_??0QImage@@QAE@HHW4Format@0@@Z)
>
> -1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QImage::~QImage(void)" (__imp_??1QImage@@UAE@XZ)
>
> -1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QImage::setPixel(int,int,unsigned int)" (__imp_?setPixel@QImage@@QAEXHHI@Z)

And etc.

Comment: Are you statically linking the executable against Qt's `gui` lib too?

Comment: No, the executable is linked dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The static library that you have created is not linked to Qt. It's just a collection of object files. The executable this static library is bound to has to be linked to Qt - and that Qt must be a static build in your case.

Comment: This project doesn't have own executable, it's used in another project that have one.

Comment: Another option would be to change the library to use Qt dynamically too, if possible of course

Comment: So if the project is build as static lib and executable that use it links Qt dynamically it is impossible to use QImage and other stuff from gui module in static lib?

Comment: No, it's not impossible. You just need to link everything that the static library needs to the target executable.

Comment: I build static lib independently, the target looks like `TARGET=[project name]` and I have errors during compilation of static lib. The executable that uses that lib is independent project. So how can I link everything to executable in way to build static build successfully?